# Navigating to an URL on a second tab fails

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to work with multiple tabs in QTP, but when I try to open a Website in a new tab, I keep getting "General Run Time error".

Here is a script to reproduce:

```
'Open a new Browser
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com"

'Browser Sync
Browser("CreationTime:=0").Sync

'Find total number of tabs in the browser window
iTabs = Browser("CreationTime:=0").GetROProperty("number of tabs")
msgbox iTabs 'Displays the value 1

'Open a new tab within the same browser
Browser("CreationTime:=0").OpenNewTab()

'Sync for new tab
Browser("CreationTime:=1").Sync

'Load some web page in the new tab
Browser("CreationTime:=1").Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com"  'General Run Time error for this line.

'Find total number of tabs in the browser window
iTabs = Browser("CreationTime:=0").GetROProperty("number of tabs")
msgbox iTabs 'Displays the value 2

'Close all the tabs in the browser window
Browser("CreationTime:=0").CloseAllTabs()
'OR -> Browser("CreationTime:=1").CloseAllTabs()
```

Comment: Your code seems fine - I tried it on UFT 12.01 - it works fine - only if a security pop up appears for second browser "i.e. yahoo.com" . it throws general run error. you might want to check that as well.

Comment: on which line does it actually gives you general run error??

Comment: Error while trying to open yahoo.in

Comment: @Pranav I'm trying to work on 11.5 and no security pop up is coming still getting the General Runtime Error.

Comment: If have an IE instance with ALM/QC running (which UFT should ignore), close it, and re-try.

Comment: Well, then let us know if you get to the bottom of it. cause i cant think of any other way.

Comment: Well even i'm thinking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Browser.Navigate is just used to change the URL of your current browser.
Since the browser with CreationTime:=1 has not been created till now, it throws a run time error.